# Add rails image_tag with jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am adding a rails image_tag with jQueryand I am trying to put a jQueryvariable in the image_tag.

```
var variable = 0;
$(targetPlayerElement).html('<%= image_tag @users[variable].profile_picture
```

I am getting undefined local variable or method `variable' error.
What is the correct syntax to do this if you even can.
thank you for all the help.

Comment: What is `@users`?

Comment: users is from the controller users = User.limit(5).order("RANDOM()")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing the content of your variable as pure Ruby and then use it in your image tag?

An example:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<% image = 'http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg' %>
<script>$('#content').html('<%= image_tag image %>')</script>
```

Comment: I agree that using `compact` first makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two things there, the `var variable = 0` is javascript and the `<%= image_tag @users[variable].profile_picture`is ruby. If you want them to be used together, the `variable`has to be parsed by js like this.

```
var variable = 0;
$(targetPlayerElement).html("<%= image_tag @users[" + variable + "].profile_picture %>")
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since `variable` is set after `<%= ... %>` is computed.

Comment: When i try that I get no implicit conversion of String into Integer error.

Comment: @Gerry you're right
@jrocc try and use only ruby

```
<% variable = 0 %>
$(targetPlayerElement).html("<%= image_tag @users[" + variable + "].profile_picture %>")
```